# Maven alternate pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is there an argument when calling a maven build to specify an alternate file in place of the standard pom.xml file name?

Basically, I have a need to run the *test* goal of my maven build with a variety of configurations.  Right now I am having to use an external script to update the standard pom with this configurations, then revert the file after.  I would much rather just be able to maintain several seperate configuration files and call maven with the specific one I need.

What I am wondering is if there is some way to override the pom.xml such as

```
mvn clean test   (uses standard pom.xml)
mvn clean test -Dmaven.source=alternate.xml
mvn clean test -Dmaven.source=alternate2.xml
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

use the -f option:

```
mvn -f <other pom file>
```

Answer (score 10):

I will leave the accepted answer as just that, since it is the proper solution to running with an alternate pom file.  However, for the use case I described above, I now feel the correct methodology would be to use maven profiles within the pom file.

[Maven Profiles Introduction](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

With profiles, all versions of the test configurations can be contained within the master pom file and then executed as follows:

```
mvn clean test -PstandardConfig
mvn clean test -PalternateConfig
mvn clean test -PanotherConfig
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this very interesting solution when I got the final answer. I follow the following approach:-

> mvn -f yourPomfil.xml goal

where the goal can be clean, verify, package, install, deploy and other maven goals