# Maven Profile exclude/include directories

Tags: java, maven, profile

I have a maven project with multiple modules :

```
- Project
-- Module 1 (war)
-- Module 2 (jar)
```

I am trying to build my Project with a profile "local".

The Module 1 uses a different web.xml depending on the profile, and it's working. 
Module 2 should be using files in Module 2 / local to compile, but it's not working since I have all the directories in the resulting jar.

Here is my pom.xml for Module 2 :

```xml
<project>
<!-- things... -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>central</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/java/local</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/java/central</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

In this version of the pom, I am trying to exclude a directory but it's not working either... I have tried specifying the includes as well.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: did you make sure you specified this profile as active when running the maven command?

Comment: I am using the Run Configuration in Eclipse. With goal : clean install ; profile : local. I think it's the equivalent for mvn -P local.

Comment: what happens if you run `mvn -p local install`?

Comment: `resources` != `sources`.

Comment: humm. I see your point. How can I do what I intend then ?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I know the profile itself is working because for Module 1 it is taken into account.

Comment: Answer found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140873/change-source-directory-in-profile-maven after the nice hint from Aleksandr M.

Comment: Good. Also take a look at compiler plugin configuration: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html.