# Define sourceDirectory in Maven profiles

Tags: java, maven

In my pom.xml file, I have:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources> .. </resources>
    <plugins> .. </plugins>
</build>
```

However, When I try to use maven profiles:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profileId</id>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <resources> .. </resources>
            <plugins> .. </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Maven gives me an error saying:

```
Unrecognised tag: 'sourceDirectory' (position: START_TAG seen ...<build>\r\n                <sourceDirectory>... @14:34)
```

Why wouldn't it let me define a source directory within a profile? Is there a way to define sourceDirectory in profiles?

Comment: Why would you like to change the sourceDirectory? Usually it does not make sense...

Comment: The project has multiple source directories. On Jenkins I want to have multiple jobs that have the same project but execute code in different directories based on maven profiles. Although I agree it's not the best approach but I was just curious to see how it works

Comment: Wrong setup. This sounds like you need to have different modules instead...I'm not sure why you need different sourceDirectories. This sounds like you need to put the different source directories into different modules and that will solve the issue and you can keep the convention of configuration pardigm in Maven.

Comment: I'll look into using modules. The project was set up the way it is when I joined, but yeah I'll try using modules. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change source directory in profile maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140873/change-source-directory-in-profile-maven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Profiles_in_POMs), you can change only few  parameters in the profile and `<sourceDirectory>` is not one of them.

I'd configure the main `<build>` to take sources from path defined by some property (eg. `src.dir`) and set this property to `src/main/java` and override it in the custom profile:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <src.dir>src/main/java</src.dir>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
        ...
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <properties>
                <src.dir>${project.build.directory}/new-src</src.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you just copy from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140873/change-source-directory-in-profile-maven ? :D