# How to make custom Source Directory in Maven

Tags: maven

How can i change the source directory in maven. There are several source folders and JSPs in WEB-INF. Its a Java Web Application.
I have Source directory as src. The JSPs are in web-inf/jsp and there are several other folders in web-inf that i want to include in my project like images etc. And also before building my project it also needs build output from another project that is in my eclipse workspace for which the build script is already there. How do i invoke build script from my current POM.

Comment: Keep the conventions. Why do you need custom directories? Source directories are `src/main/java` Java sources..`src/main/webapp` for JSPs etc.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please provide more information. Try to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change source directory in profile maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140873/change-source-directory-in-profile-maven)

Comment: I have Source directory as src. The JSPs are in web-inf/jsp and there are several other folders in web-inf that i want to include in my project like images etc. And also before building my project it also needs build output from another project that is in my eclipse workspace for which the build script is already there. How do i invoke build script from my current POM.