# IntellijIDE Marking top directory as sources root causes src.main.java.com.mycompany.xyz

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

Normally when I mark top level directory of maven project that is structured as main/java/src it finds the correct package com.mycompany.xyz but on one project I notice it interprets the start of the package incorrectly as main.java.src.com.mycompany.xyz what is the correct root directory to use as source and why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`src/main/java` is the correct source directory for the Maven projects. See [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html#introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout).

IntelliJ IDEA should import it automatically from the `pom.xml`. Make sure you don't override it anywhere in the build file [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142756/104891).

Comment: I dont know because there is also main/test/java not just src/main/java

Comment: If you follow the link in the answer, you'll see that the tests reside in `src/test/java`. It's the Tests source root that is also configured automatically by IntelliJ IDEA when you import the project from `pom.xml`.