# Lombok Maven javadoc:aggregate report with generated sources

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, lombok, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a multimodule java project built with Maven to which I want to generate javadocs with `javadoc:aggregate`. The project structure looks like:

```
parent
├─lomboklib
└─other
```

I am also using [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) to generate some methods in the project. I have successfully configured it to work with single modules by first running [delombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) with the [Lombok maven plugin](https://github.com/awhitford/lombok.maven). For single modules (lomboklib), this will generate source code in

```
target/generated-sources/delombok
```

which is then processed by **maven-javadoc-plugin** and the **javadoc** tool. This was originally solved in [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930955/1119345).

How can I configure the `javadoc:aggregate` report to also use the generated sources?

I've put up a sandbox of the problem with all the module definitions in [Github](https://github.com/vaisala-oss/lombok-maven-multimodule). Ideally, I should be able to run

```
mvn clean compile javadoc:aggregate
```

In the parent project, and have the whole thing compile and get javadocs for the entire project.

Comment: Great question. Same issue on a project with dozens of modules which all use lombok. You'd hope there was some way to overide the subdir that javadoc:aggregate looks in as it recurses through the models. We are running with the hacky solution from @Ben M. which is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a workaround build configuration that will create aggregated javadocs from generated sources, although the call sequence has two steps:

```
mvn package
mvn -N pre-site
```

The build configuration is now published in [Github](https://github.com/vaisala-oss/lombok-maven-multimodule). The current version only supports a project tree of depth one, but can of course be modified. It works by gathering the dependencies under the parents `target` directory and then running the included *Ant* script.

Finally, if running under Jenkins, the `mvn -N pre-site` can be invoked in the same job through **Execute shell** post step. Publishing the javadocs  in our version of Jenkins required using the post-build action "**Use publishers from another project**".

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the example project from Github to recreate your problem and discovered that it was because the `lombok-maven-plugin` was configured unnecessarily at the top-level pom -- it is only needed for the module that contains lombok code.  By simply removing that configuration, `javadoc:aggregate` behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this same problem, and I've been able to work around it by referencing the source paths directly from the parent project.

Try this configuration for your parent pom's maven-javadoc-plugin.

```
<configuration>
    <sourcepath>
        lomboklib/target/generated-sources/delombok;
        other/target/generated-sources/delombok
    </sourcepath>
</configuration>
```

It's really not ideal.  It feels like a bit of a hack.