# Javadoc error on @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to generate the javadoc using JDK 8 for a bunch of codes using lombok.

I am getting the error below:

```
error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] symbol: class __
```

Any advice will be much appreciated on how to resolve the error above.

Update: the error is happening using the maven javadoc plugin configured as below:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <!--
            <configuration>
                <doclet>ch.raffael.doclets.pegdown.PegdownDoclet</doclet>
                <docletArtifact>
                    <groupId>ch.raffael.pegdown-doclet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pegdown-doclet</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                </docletArtifact>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions>
            </configuration>
            -->
        </plugin>
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, as it happens under Maven. The original ticket is for IntelliJ

Comment: For somebody who is looking for a solution like me: I found a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329965/how-to-ignore-the-java-source-directory-during-maven-compilation

Comment: This Q is totally unrelated to the "duplicate" Q and was incorrectly flagged.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, resolved by:

1. Configuring `lombok-maven-plugin` to

   1. Delombok the classes into `target/delombok` directory
   2. Don't `addOutputDirectory` to the compiler source paths
2. Configure `maven-javadoc-plugin` to look into the `target/delombok` directory

A good explanation is also at this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11329965/1998422)

Also, bare in mind that [onConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) is an experimental feature and that with jdk8, you should use `(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)` instead of jdk7-style `onConstructor = @__(@Autowired)`

Here is my full config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok-maven-plugin-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                 <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>
                     ${project.build.directory}/delombok
                </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin-version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>target/generated-sources/delombok</sourcepath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: where did you find that config file ?

Answer (score 4):

Adding here just for future reference as on my case I was trying to build on Intelij and the error was due to compiler annotation processors being disabled.

To enable it, go to Intelij preferences, open *"Build, Execution, Deployment"* -> *"Compiler"* -> *"Annotation Processors"* and make sure *"Enable annotation processing"* is enabled

[image: Enable annotation processing Intelij preference]

Answer (score 0):

If you use intellij Idea go to setting and add Lombok plugin to your intellij idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FXZG.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32303614)

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason for this error (caused by `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` to be exact) was a duplicated `@Transactional` annotation in another class (overlooked after rebasing a branch in Git). Removing the duplicate resolved the issue immediately, maybe this piece of information helps somebody in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers that are written worked for me, and I don't think the answers are directly relevant to what OP alluded to is the main problem (which was my main problem as well).

I was trying to make the JavaDocs integration work with SpringDoc in a Spring Boot application I had. [With the example given in the SpringDoc documentation itself](https://springdoc.org/#javadoc-support), things didn't really work and I got the error that OP got.

Googling around a bit more, [I found this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74287938/9713261)

Following it, I just added the following to my pom.xml to make things work:

**Add the following to your dependency:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.therapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>therapi-runtime-javadoc</artifactId>
        <version>0.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Then add the following plugin to your `<build>` section**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>com.github.therapi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe</artifactId>
                        <version>0.15.0</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```